# recursively copy files by creating required paths in destination directory using python

Tags: python, scp, directory-structure

I want to recursively copy certain files from server location to my machine preserving the directory structure.

server structure

```
/opt/shared/dir1/dir2/dir3/sample.json  
/opt/shared/dir1/dir2/dir3/sample2.json   
/opt/shared/dir1/dir2/sample.json  
/opt/shared/dir1/dir2/sample2.json
```

I want to find all sample.json starting from /opt/shared/dir1 and copy these to my local machine maintaining the structure.

/home/users/a/dir1/dir2/dir3/sample.json
/home/users/a/dir1/dir2/sample.json

I am using python2.7

I can use os.walk at server to get all the files but
How do I copy to create the directory structure?
How to use scp so as to copy to my machine?

```
import os
import fnmatch
top=/opt/shared/dir1
allfiles=[]
filepattern="sample.json"
for path, dirlist, filelist in os.walk(top):
        for name in fnmatch.filter(filelist,filepattern):
          allfiles.append(os.path.join(path,name))
```

Comment: Is the script executed on the server or on your local machine?

Comment: I was executing it on the server and hence I am restricted to python 2.7

Comment: In that case a shell script might be an easier solution. You could reuse your python script to dump the file list, read each line to create the directory with `ssh user@localmachine "mkdir /path/"` and then `scp` the file.